# where condition is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In usrshow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for userview_path, :method => 'get' do |f|%>    
<%= f.collection_select :city, Place.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'select place' %>
<%= text_field_tag :search %>
<%= submit_tag "Search"%>
<% end %>
```

In hotels_controller

```
 def usrshow
    if params[:search].present?
        @hotels = Hotel.where(["city_id = ? and hotels LIKE ?",params[:city], "%#{params[:search]}%"])
        else
        @hotels = Hotel.all(:order => 'id DESC')
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @hotels }
    end
end
```

I have to search and display hotels based on the selected city.But this code is not working.

Comment: "Is not working" is not enough information. Do you get an error? What does it mean "it's not working"?

Comment: This code is not searching the fields.It's returning only empty fields

Comment: do u have a field like 'hotels' or 'name' in hotels table?

Comment: The search process is correct,but the city_id is not getting.

Comment: Is the city_id a field in hotels table? or any associated table?

Comment: What do you have in your log after submitting the request?

Comment: The city_id present in hotels table

Comment: Parameters: {"commit"=>"Search", "search"=>"m", "/userview"=>{"city"=>""}, "utf8"=>"✓"}   
.....                                                                      SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE (city_id = NULL and hotels LIKE '%m%') LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

Comment: <%= form_for userview_path, :method => 'get' do |f|%>  
This is showing the form is posting to userview_path means userview action of the controller, but u have written the search functions in usrshow , Plz check again .

Comment: get "userview" => "hotels#usrshow", :as => "userview". I'm having this in routes.rb.

Comment: So somewhere problem in representing collection_select
try this code
<%= f.collection_select :city, Place.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'select place'} %>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need *[]* brackets in your *where*:

```
@hotels = Hotel.where("city_id = ? and hotels LIKE ?",params[:city], "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Specify your error. Not working is a **bad** description

You can check your *SQL* query in console:

```
Hotel.where("city_id = ? and hotels LIKE ?",params[:city], "%#{params[:search]}%").to_sql
```

It will show you the exact query. You can run it your DB and verify the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple search condition

```
def usrshow
    if params[:search].present?
     @hotels = Hotel.where("city_id = ? AND hotels LIKE ",params[:city],"%#{params[:search]}%").order('id DESC')
        else
        @hotels = Hotel.all(:order => 'id DESC')
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @hotels }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Search", "search"=>"m", "/userview"=>{"city"=>""}, "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

Means `params[:city]` is `nil` i think you have to use `params["/userview"]["city"]` instead

like

```
@hotels = Hotel.where("city_id = ? AND hotels LIKE ",
                       params["/userview"]["city"],
                       "%#{params[:search]}%").order('id DESC')
```